# after encrypting with aes my file is one block longer

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am using AES with cipher mode CBC and default padding (I am not setting it, so I guess it'll set a default padding mode).

When i try, as a example/test, to encrypt a .txt file with just a few words written (consider it as if it were for example, 50 bytes); the output file is one block higher, so, for example 4096+16=5012. I guess that's cause it reads a complete block of 4096 bytes, encodes it, and writes it. But then he adds 16 extra bytes, don't know why; because padding is supposed to fill a block.

My code is:

```
using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
{

     myAes.BlockSize = myAes.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
     myAes.KeySize = myAes.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
     myAes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
     myAes.GenerateIV();
     myAes.GenerateKey();
     ICryptoTransform encryptor = myAes.CreateEncryptor(myAes.Key, myAes.IV );
     CryptoStream csCrypt = new CryptoStream(FileOUT, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

     do
     {
          bytesRead = FileIN.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);
          if (bytesRead != 0)
          {
               csCrypt.Write(buffer, 0, bufferLen);
          }
     } while (bytesRead != 0);

     csCrypt.Close();
     csCrypt.Dispose();
     FileIN.Close();
     FileIN.Dispose();
     FileOUT.Close();
     FileOUT.Dispose();
}
```

Is that right? is there any way that i can fix that 16-extra-bytes adding?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: but, why those extra 16 bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AES with a mode of operation such as CBC or ECB only works on full blocks (multiple of 16 bytes) which is why a padding is needed. When the plaintext is already a multiple of the block size, then an additional padding block must be added, because otherwise you wouldn't know how many bytes to remove after decryption.

Since 4096 bytes is a multiple of the block size, a full padding block is added and then everything is encrypted resulting in 5012 ciphertext bytes.

This is how the PKCS#7 padding operates (sometimes referred to as PKCS#5 padding). If you can be certain that you will always read bytes as a multiple of the block size, then you can set

```
myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```

for encryption and decryption.

Since you're using CBC mode with a randomly generated IV, you need to store it somewhere. It's generally a good idea to write the IV at the beginning of the ciphertext, so you don't have to keep track of it with other means. It doesn't have to be secret, but only needs to be unpredictable.

Comment: THANKS!!! That's what i was just asking, the answer was easy and simple. I know about to storing the IV, but that code was just a first test with encryption (in this case AES).